# Streamed file is corrupt

Tags: php, download

Everytime I use the code below to stream an image file to me the file comes back as corrupt. The image file most certainly is not corrupt though and is fine when I open it through my ftp. Am I missing something?

```
$fileTry = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file_path));
if($fileTry === false) 
{
    die('no file');
} 
else 
{
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file_path));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));
    readfile($file_path);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Do you know its type? Why use `application/octet-stream` instead of its actual mime type?

Comment: If you don't know the type, [you can find out](http://php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php)

Comment: I figured octet would work just the same?

Comment: I'm not sure it will. Test it with the known type of the file you're testing with: `image/jpeg` for example or `image/png`.

Comment: Changing the code to header('Content-Type:' . image_type_to_mime_type($file_path)); got me the same problem. The image always comes back corrupt.

Comment: To test, you need to hard-code the image type assuming you know it for the one you're working with. `image_type_to_mime_type()` doesn't accept a file path, it accepts an image constant. You would first need to use `getimagesize($file_path)` and read the `IMAGETYPE_` constant from the array it returns. http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: Found out that "mime_content_type($file_path);" returns the same thing as doing $type = image_type_to_mime_type($mimeConstant[2]); $type = mime_content_type($file_path);...still doesn't work for some reason. Could this be a server problem?

Comment: I doubt it's a server problem, the file in `$file_path` is a real image, or base64 encoded string?

Comment: It appears to be a real images. I will try to decode using base64 and see if that works. Even if it was base 64 wouldn't it still work as long as header is correct.

Comment: They are not base64 encoded. So I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: Did you hard code the mime type into the `Content-type` header as I suggested earlier?